# Why is the UITabBarController default background color not shown in the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to generate a `UITabBarController` programatically. This is how I did it in application delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    func makeItem(title: String, image: String) -> UITabBarItem {
        return UITabBarItem(
            title: NSLocalizedString(title, comment: ""),
            image: UIImage(systemName: image),
            tag: 0
        )
    }

    firstViewController = ViewController(backgroundColor: .blue)
    firstViewController.tabBarItem = makeItem(title: "First", image: "books.vertical.fill")
    
    secondViewController = ViewController(backgroundColor: .red)
    secondViewController.tabBarItem = makeItem(title: "Second", image: "books.vertical.fill")
    
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
  
    tabBarController.setViewControllers([firstViewController, secondViewController], animated: true)
    
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

The result is:

[image]

When I test this in real device it seems normal:

[image]

My Xcode version is 14.2, iOS Simulator 16.2. My target iOS version is 13. I reinstalled Xcode and it didn't change. What would be the reason of this? I have zero clue. I also tried some public repository example of `UITabBarController` and the result is same with my code. Default tabbar is not shown properly.

Comment: Try this:

if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .white
        tabBarController.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    } else {
        tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = .white
    }

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. But no it didn't solve. result is same.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is just a simulator bug, since on device everything works fine, but nothing works on simulator. Try updating your Xcode, there's a newer version out, 14.3.1